# Open link in a browser from the feed in webview

Tags: android, webview

Hi I have a string i am feeding into WebView, it loads fine. That feed contains hyperlink and once i click on them it opens content in the WebView. Also those hyperlink require double tab.

This is how i load article feed.

```
 mArticleWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mArticleWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, mArticles.getArticle(), "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
```

What am i missing? Thanks

Comment: but what is your problem?

Comment: You want to open link in browser instead of opening in webview?

Comment: Yeah. But article feed contains few links so i cant just say 'wv.loadUrl(url)', coz i have e.g. 5 URLs in the feed.

Comment: what you want,opening few links in browser and rest are in webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add WebViewClient to your WebView in order to open it in the WebView. Something like

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To open link in browser,try this

```
mArticleWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                  mContext.startActivity(intent);
                  return true;
    }
});
```